# How to protect JSON from firebase database?

Tags: json, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

first of all, I'm a beginner! I would like to know if anyone knows how to protect the firebase database, like has a certain link created automatically, example: https://example.firebaseio.com/.json If a user accesses it, they can see the entire JSON and copy. How can I stop this?

Answer (score 1):

That's what Firebase Real Time Database Rules are for. When rules are set up correctly and someone attempts to access that address they will see this

```
{
  "error" : "Permission denied"
}
```

There's a great guide to get you started [Understand Firebase Realtime Database Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security)

Note that the default rules for Real Time database will produce that error. Here they are for reference.

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

And you can test it by opening  web brownser and navigating to

```
https://your-database.firebaseio.com/.json
```

If you're using Firestore, the rules are a bit different so here's a link for those [Structuring Cloud Firestore Security Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure)

Based on a comment, the Firebase Real Time Database can also be disabled through the Firebase console.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! But, I want to make that when the user enters the link it will be redirected to the Firebase site instead of a page with the JSON string from my database. My rules are like "free to read" and "authentication to write", if possible I would like to continue with them anyway...

Comment: @user9761266 That's not what your question asked. You asked *they can see the entire JSON and copy. How can I stop this?* and you STOP it through firebase rules. Your comment here is an entirely different question about *redirecting* not about *stopping*. You should consider updating your question with your actual question so it's clear what you are asking.

Comment: Is that I do not understand much, I will try to explain! Here is an example: https://inkr-9a954.firebaseio.com/.json Note that it will return an error, and what I want is exactly that, but I don't know how to do it, I have no idea :(

Comment: @user9761266 That's done using Firebase rules and/or the firebase console as mentioned in my answer. You can allow or disallow access through rules or totally disable the database through the Firebase console. If you disable the database, it will produce the error showing in your link *"error" : "The Firebase database 'inkr-9a954' has been disabled by a database owner."* See my updated answer.

Comment: No, that's not it. I don't want to disable, what I want is to return that error "Permission denied" when trying to access JSON from my database. I know it can be done in the rules, I just want you to show me some example please.

Comment: @user9761266 The link in your comment shows *disabled* so I showed you how to do that. If that's not what you want then you shouldn't include a link that shows that. Look at my answer. See where it says *"error" : "Permission denied"*, according to your comment you want to see the same thing. If you set up Firebase Rules, that's exactly what you will see. In fact that's a message from *my* database if you try to access it because I have rules set up.

Comment: Exactly, can you teach me how to make the database return this error when trying to access?

Comment: @user9761266 It's thoroughly covered in the documentation I linked in my answer. I just updated the answer as well to show example rules that will produce that exact error message.

Comment: I see, in this case users will only be able to read / write to the database if they are authenticated, so that will return that error. But at the same time, this will be forcing my app users to sign in :(